# Symfony: error while rendering block - Unable to find template

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-3.3

I am using Sonata's block bundle and Symfony 3.3 to develop an application. I have configured a block service for displaying YouTube videos.

The service includes the following code:

```
    $blockContext->setSetting('template', 'AppBundle:Components:videoElement.html.twig');
    return $this->renderResponse($blockContext->getTemplate(), array(
        'block' => $block,
        'settings' => $settings,
        'media' => $media,
        'framehtml' => $frameHtml,
        'provider_reference' => $providerReference,

    ), $response);
```

When I use the service on my laptop, it works well. When I shift to another environment, videos no longer display, and I get the following error:

> [2018-04-05 11:24:23] app.ERROR: [cms::renderBlock] block.id=13 -
>   error while rendering block - Unable to find template
>   "AppBundle:Components:videoElement.html.twig" (looked into:
>   /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/app/Resources/views,
>   /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form,
>   /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views).
>   {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to
>   find template \"AppBundle:Components:videoElement.html.twig\" (looked
>   into: /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/app/Resources/views,
>   /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form,
>   /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views).
>   at
>   /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php:127,
>   Twig_Error_Loader(code: 0): Unable to find template
>   \"AppBundle:Components:videoElement.html.twig\" (looked into:
>   /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/app/Resources/views,
>   /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form,
>   /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/vendor/knplabs/knp-menu/src/Knp/Menu/Resources/views).
>   at
>   /srv/htdocs/vgms-core/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:232)"}
>   []

The template exists and lives in 
`src/AppBundle/Resources/views/components/videoElement.html.twig`.

How can I explicitly tell Symfony where to look for this template?

Comment: Where is your template into `AppBundle` or `app/Resources/views`?

Comment: Read [Template Naming and Locations](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations)

Comment: Thanks, gp_sflover -- that worked. I accessed my template with `@App/components/videoElement.html.twig` which did the trick. If you want to expand this into an answer, I will mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As showed in [Referencing Templates in a Bundle (Symfony 3.3 version)](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle) you can use the Twig syntax `@BundleName/directory/filename.html.twig` to specify where a specific bundle template lives.

By default specific bundle templates are stored in the `BundleName/Resources/views` folder and could be referred using `@App/videoElement.html.twig`, so in your case you only need to indicate the added `components` folder with `@App/components/videoElement.html.twig`.